# Scale out queue triggered azure function behavior in AppServicePlan

Tags: azure, azure-functions, scaling, azure-app-service-plans, queuetrigger

I have developed a queue triggered azure function in c#. The function is running on the AppService plan. We want to implement custom auto-scale out. We are planning to increases the instance count by 1 when the CPU percentage is above 60%

My questions are:

1. Is this a good idea to increase the instance count at 60%?
2. I have research and found that for blob triggered azure function
   there is a mechanism that will prevent two instances to pick the
   same queue entry. Its there the same mechanism for C# Queue
   Triggered Azure Function?
3. In my function code, I have written Thread.Sleep(3000) to sleep the
   thread in some conditions. Can it cause any issue while scaling out?
4. Is there anything else I should keep in mind while scaling out in my
   scenario?

Thanks in advance.